# Добавить (удалить) строки в checkedListBox с привязкой данных

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в c# winforms vs2010 решить следующую задачу:
На форме есть checkedListBox1, в который при открытии формы загружаются несколько фамилий (строк) из файла mdb. А также на форме есть 31 шт TextBox-ов (TextBox_d1 - TextBox_d31). С помощью определенных кнопок в TextBox-сы заносятся данные. С помощью кнопки "btn_Click" осуществляется привязка Фамилий к коллекции people, и текстбоксов к свойствам Value. Вопрос: как осуществить подобную привязку при добавлении (и удалении) нового человека (фамилии) в checkedListBox1 по кнопке на форме? Т.е. после добавления всех фамилий в checkedListBox1, у меня получается выполнить привязку (код ниже), а как дополнять (и удалять) checkedListBox1 новыми фамилиями с привязкой?

```
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
        BindingList<Person> people = new BindingList<Person>();


    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox[] TxtArray_d = new TextBox[] { TextBox_d1, TextBox_d2, TextBox_d3, ..., TextBox_d31 };

            people = new BindingList<Person>();

            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.Items)
            {
                Person p = new Person
                {
                    Id = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item),
                    Name = item.ToString(),
                    Value1 = TextBox_d1.Text,
                    Value2 = TextBox_d2.Text,
                    Value3 = TextBox_d3.Text,
                    ...
                    Value31 = TextBox_d31.Text
                };
                people.Add(p);
            }

            //Привязываем коллекцию к компоненту:
            var listBox = ((ListBox)checkedListBox1);
            listBox.DataSource = people;
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

            for (int num = 0; num < 31; ++num)
            {
                TxtArray_d[num].DataBindings.Clear();
            }

            for (int num = 0; num < 31; ++num)
            {
                int num1;
                num1 = num + 1;
                TxtArray_d[num].DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value" + num1, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            }

        }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //31 свойство, по количеству дней (TBox_d*):
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
        public string Value3 { get; set; }
        ...
        public string Value31 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

После первой привязки вам больше не нужно ничего привязывать. Ваш листбокс просто начинает отображать состояние [BindingList people]. Манипулируйте дальше с people (people.Add, people.Remove, people[0].Value1 =… и т.д.)